# Javascript Array - Creating from string pulled from textbox (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a php script which loops through and creates a string of values (see below) this value is then added to a hidden textbox. Now what I want to do is pull this value into my javascript  using jQuery and create an array.

$events contains the following values:

```
{date:'2014-01-29'},{date:'2014-01-30'},{date:'2014-01-31'},{date:'2014-02-01'},{date:'2014-02-03'}
```

Here is the textfield:

```
<input type="hidden" id="events" value="<?=$events?>">
```

Here is the line in my js file to create the array:

```
var eventarray=[$("#events").val()];
```

Now when I alert() eventarray in my js it gives me:

```
{date:'2014-01-29'},{date:'2014-01-30'},{date:'2014-01-31'},{date:'2014-02-01'},{date:'2014-02-03'}
```

but what I need it to return is (so I can use the array correctly):

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

I am trying to pass a dynamic set of dates from my db to a calendar (I'm using CLNDR).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JSON.parse`

```
var eventarray=JSON.parse('['+$("#events").val()+']');
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/U6fv6/1/)

or in jQuery `$.parseJSON()`

```
var eventarray=$.parseJSON('['+$("#events").val()+']');
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/2hqYW/)

Keep in mind that your JSON string needs to be well-formed, and that means double-quoting property names and values,hence change the `$events` variable as follows

```
{"date":"2014-01-29"},{"date":"2014-01-30"},{"date":"2014-01-31"},{"date":"2014-02-01"},{"date":"2014-02-03"}
```

[**Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

Comment: yay! this worked! :) Thank you. (I don't have the ability to down vote, so that wasn't me.)

Answer (score -1):

What you should do is amend your output so that you produce a JSON string (ie *double* quote the properties as well as the keys):

```
var json = '{"date":"2014-01-29"},{"date":"2014-01-30"},{"date":"2014-01-31"},{"date":"2014-02-01"},{"date":"2014-02-03"}';
```

This isn't quite proper JSON yet. You need to amend the string like so:

```
var str = '[' + json + ']';
```

Then parse it:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(str);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/gu7ZF/)